# Adjust spacing between list elements in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

Is there a way to adjust the spacing between list elements in Word 2010?

I can apply a style to the list, and then edit the style, and edit the spacing before and after the element, but this applies to the list, not the list element.

There are no styles I can see which can be applied to a list element allowing the spacing between list elements to be adjusted.

If I select 1 list element, and then adjust the spacing before or after in the Page Layout tab, this applies to the whole list, not the list element, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Line Spacing option.

Select all the list elements. Then in the Home tab under paragraph section, to the left of the paint bucket you'll see the Line Spacing button. In it there are values like 1, 1.5, 2... Select a value from it or you can set a custom value also.

Answer (score 3):

Use the after (or before) spacing in the paragraph section rather than the line spacing, that way you won't alter the spacing *within* each list item:

Right click on the style -> modify style -> click format -> click paragraph (it's in the spacing section with 0pt 0pt etc.)  Don't forget to un-check "Don’t add space between paragraphs of the same style" for this to work.

Comment: This answer is more correct, but you have to remember to un-check "Don’t add space between paragraphs of the same style".